# When Lead is Converted want to create an another contact

Tags: lead-conversion

when we convert a lead one contact automatically created. other than tht i want to create another contact when lead is converted means when lead is converted 2 contact shuld be created.

here is my code:

```
trigger LeadConversionTrigger on Lead (after insert) {

    map<Id, Lead> mapNewLead = trigger.newMap; 
    List<Contact> otherContact = new List<Contact>(); 
    for(Lead objLead: mapNewLead.values()) 
    { 
        if (objLead.IsConverted == true ) 
        { 
            otherContact.add(new contact(LastName = objLead.Owner_2_Name__c,
                                         Phone = objLead.Owner_2_Phone__c, 
                                         Email = objLead.Owner_2_Email_Address__c,
                                         Owner_1_City__c =objLead.Owner_2_City__c, 
                                         Birthdate =objLead.Owner_2_DOB__c,
                                         Owner1_Home_Address__c=objLead.Owner_2_Home_Address__c,
                                         Title=objLead.Owner_2_Job_Title__c, 
                                         Social_Security_Number__c=objLead.Owner_2_SSN__c,
                                         Owner_1_State__c=objLead.Owner_2_State__c,
                                         Owner_1_Zip__c=objLead.Owner_2_Zip__c,
                                         AccountId =objLead.convertedAccountId));            

        } 
    insert otherContact; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger is only firing on insert, but it should be on update:

```
trigger LeadConversionTrigger on Lead (after update) {
```

You probably also want to check only "on conversion", since Leads can be updated after conversion:

```
Lead objOldLead = Trigger.oldMap.get(objLead.Id);
if (!objOldLead.IsConverted && objLead.IsConverted) {
```

Finally, you have a DML inside the for loop, which will cause mass conversion DML to fail:

```
        } 
        // DML operation was inside loop here
    }
    insert otherContact; 
}
```